# I want to enter the data in a textbox through scanner device, where I want to avoid the manual entering in that text box?

Tags: html

```
<form id='form' method='GET'>
    <input type="text" name="text" readonly/>
</form>
```

The above code is only avoiding the manual entering, but it is also preventing from scanner device also, please help me if any possible

Comment: Clarify what you want. What scanner device? You mean like scanning book with scanner and adding outputted image bin code to input field?

Comment: So, users shouldn't be able to type in the textfield. You can disable specific fields quite easily, but i don't understand the other half of your question: "input text through scanner device"?

Comment: You probably can't, since the scanner is emulating key presses and there is no way for the browser to know if the chars came from the scanner or the keyboard.

Comment: hmmmmm.... Interesting and maybe not so trivial question, but not too complex also. You can read the delay between key strokes (coming from keyboard or scanner) to figure out if it's 'human' or 'scanner' input and reset the value if necessary.  (not using readonly)

Comment: here, I want to fill the text box using barcode scanner, where I dont want to allow the users to enter the data manually(through keyboard)